# translate typescript to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, translate

I need this code is in **Javascript**

I am not specialized in language typescript.

this is code for play music and record audio in mobile with nativescript

do not think **GitHub** quickly give answer

[in github issues](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-audio/issues/56)

```
import { TNSPlayer } from 'nativescript-audio';

export class YourClass {
    private _player: TNSPlayer;

    constructor() {
        this._player = new TNSPlayer();
        this._player.initFromFile({
            audioFile: '~/audio/song.mp3', // ~ = app directory
            loop: false,
            completeCallback: this._trackComplete.bind(this),
            errorCallback: this._trackError.bind(this)
        }).then(() => {

            this._player.getAudioTrackDuration().then((duration) => {
                // iOS: duration is in seconds
                // Android: duration is in milliseconds
                console.log(`song duration:`, duration);
            });
        });
    }

    public togglePlay() {
        if (this._player.isAudioPlaying()) {
            this._player.pause();
        } else {
            this._player.play();
        }
    }

    private _trackComplete(args: any) {
        console.log('reference back to player:', args.player);

        // iOS only: flag indicating if completed succesfully
        console.log('whether song play completed successfully:', args.flag);
    }

    private _trackError(args: any) {
        console.log('reference back to player:', args.player);
        console.log('the error:', args.error);

        // Android only: extra detail on error
        console.log('extra info on the error:', args.extra);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Webpack or any Angular (2+) seed project, even angular-cli, all your TypeScript code will "compiled" to ECMAScript and you can choose the version (from 5 to 7).

Just open tsconfig.json. *target* will give a concrete version of ECMAScript you need.

```
 "compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"baseUrl": "src",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

Run `build` and get your JavaScript file from the *outDir* directory.

Comment: I do not want TypeScript language I use. I want the code to JavaScript programming language is direct

Answer (score 4):

You can use typescript playground for instant conversion from typescript to javascript.
Here is the url http://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Or You can install typescript compiler in your machine and run tsc .

Comment: I certainly did search before asking.
Indicating that output does not work

Comment: It's because nativescript-audio itself is a library. This conversion will not download the library, it only converts the code that's it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the TypeScript Compiler (tsc) to do that. For your snippet the output is this:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var nativescript_audio_1 = require("nativescript-audio");
var YourClass = (function () {
    function YourClass() {
        var _this = this;
        this._player = new nativescript_audio_1.TNSPlayer();
        this._player.initFromFile({
            audioFile: '~/audio/song.mp3',
            loop: false,
            completeCallback: this._trackComplete.bind(this),
            errorCallback: this._trackError.bind(this)
        }).then(function () {
            _this._player.getAudioTrackDuration().then(function (duration) {
                // iOS: duration is in seconds
                // Android: duration is in milliseconds
                console.log("song duration:", duration);
            });
        });
    }
    YourClass.prototype.togglePlay = function () {
        if (this._player.isAudioPlaying()) {
            this._player.pause();
        }
        else {
            this._player.play();
        }
    };
    YourClass.prototype._trackComplete = function (args) {
        console.log('reference back to player:', args.player);
        // iOS only: flag indicating if completed succesfully
        console.log('whether song play completed successfully:', args.flag);
    };
    YourClass.prototype._trackError = function (args) {
        console.log('reference back to player:', args.player);
        console.log('the error:', args.error);
        // Android only: extra detail on error
        console.log('extra info on the error:', args.extra);
    };
    return YourClass;
}());
exports.YourClass = YourClass;
```